# UITableView: table view scrolling makes images disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

I am working with one iOS application it has two tables placed side by side, each table view holds images. Both table views having the auto scrolling and manual scrolling functionality. By default both tableviews in auto scrolling mode, but the problem is when user did manual scrolling images in table view become disappear (loading images very lately) and its happening when table view state is moving from auto scrolling to manual scrolling and manual scrolling to auto scrolling. currently I am using static images only (not dynamic and not from server). In future i have to use with dynamic data(images) coming from server.

Any ideas to fix this issue that will be very helpful to me.

Comment: post your code  here.

Comment: Althought i't a bad solution but setting reuseIdentifier to nil may solve ur problem.

Comment: @rptwsthi As you said, that's a bad solution.  You shouldn't take shortcuts like that just to get things "working"

Comment: @iWasRobbed +1 for scolding me Sir! :)

Comment: https://github.com/adamalex/fast-scrolling this was a good solution before twitter bought the company. However there is a repo on github which you can have a look.

Comment: have you set the image outside the the block if(cell==nil) and are you loading the images from url?

Comment: Thanks for all responses... I am using reuseIdentifier but that is not an issue and i am setting the image out side the block if (cell == nil) and currently I am using images in local only, which are not coming from server or url.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of your `UITableViewCells` and all their subviews. Sometimes (at least for me) the sizes will be at 0 and then when that frame (which is 0 points high) goes off the screen, the image will disappear.